# How to use variables from a protected method in another method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am attempting to recreate a C# Console Application I made, but in ASP.Net Web Forms this time, but I've been having a bit of trouble with my buttons.

I made 2 buttons, one to initialize a variable with a value, and the other to use said variable's value, but when I attempt to use the variable I receive an error saying that the variable does not exist in the current context.

Here is an example of what my code looks like:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int answer = 5;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(txtAnswer.Text) == answer)
    {
        lblQuestion.Text = "You're Right!";
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do what your post suggests it does "one to initialize a variable with a value, and the other to use said variable's value."

Comment: The if statement in the second button is supposed to use the value of the the variable "answer" that has been initialized in the first button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `answer` variable is local to the click event handler. It does not exist outside of it. You have to define a field:

```
int answer;
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    answer = 5;
}
```

As a general rule: Everything inside curly braces is visible only within those braces (except when you can define a visibility, like `public` or `internal`). This is called [*scope*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx).

Note that the value is lost once the page has been sent. If you want to preserve the value across requests you have to store the value in a more permanent way, for example in the view state.

Comment: Not only is the value lost when the page is sent, but if you were to set `answer = 5` in another protected method (e.g. on DataBound or something else), then that value would only be `5` within that same protected method.